# how to make threads print in order java

Tags: java, multithreading

A few people may have seen this code earlier, I have continued on it, and now i am having issues with null pointers, and indexOutOfBound exceptions. the index out of bound errors come up sometimes dependant on either the number of players or the hand size.

This is the code, The main CardGame class

```
public class CardGame
{
   static Player[] players;
   static int handSize;
   static Queue<Card>[] playingDeckArray;
   static int playersNum;

   public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println( "\nHello, how many players would you like" );
        playersNum = Integer.parseInt(Checks.userInputCheck( "\\d" ));
        System.out.println( "\nHow many cards should each player begin with" );
        int handSize = Integer.parseInt(Checks.userInputCheck( "\\d" ));
        System.out.println( "\nWhich strategy would you like to use 1 or 2" );
        int strategy = Integer.parseInt(Checks.userInputCheck( "[12]$" ));

        Logger.createDeck( playersNum, handSize );

        makePlayers( playersNum, handSize, strategy );

        makePlayingDecks( playersNum );

        dealInitialHand( playersNum, players, handSize );

        makePlayerOutputs();

        //Player.startPauseThread();

        for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
           logInitialHand(players[i]);
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
           isWinner( players[i]);
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
            new Thread(players[i]).start();
        }
   }

   private static void makePlayers(  int noPlayers, int noCardsInHand, int strategyChosen){
       players = new Player[noPlayers];
       for( int i = 0; i < noPlayers; i++){
           players[i] = new Player( strategyChosen, noCardsInHand, i+1 );
           players[i].fillHand();
       }

   }

   private static void dealInitialHand(int noPlayers, Player[] players, int noCardsInHand ){
       System.out.println( "\nPlease enter the name of the deck file" );
       File theDeck = new File (Checks.userInputCheck( "deckfile.txt" ) );

       int line = 0;

       try{
           Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner( theDeck );
           for( int h = 0; h < noCardsInHand; h++){
               for( int p = 0; p < noPlayers; p++){
                    line = Integer.parseInt( fileScanner.nextLine() );
                    players[p].setHand( line, h );
               }
           }

           for( int t = 0; t < noCardsInHand; t++){
               for( int i = 0; i < playingDeckArray.length; i++ ){
                   line = Integer.parseInt( fileScanner.nextLine() );
                   playingDeckArray[i].add( new Card(line) );
                }
               }

            }catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       seePlayerHands();
   }

   private static void makePlayingDecks( int noPlayers ){
       playingDeckArray = new Queue[noPlayers];
       for( int i = 0; i < playingDeckArray.length; i++ ){
           playingDeckArray[i] = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Card>();
           System.out.println( playingDeckArray[i] );
        }

   }

   private static void seePlayerHands(){
       for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
          System.out.println( players[i].getPlayerName() + "'s hand is currently" );
          players[i].seeHand();
        }
   }

   private static void makePlayerOutputs(){
       for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
           Logger.createPlayerOutputs( players[i].getPlayerName());
        }
   }

   private static void logInitialHand( Player player ){
       Logger.addToOutput( player.getPlayerName(), ( player.getPlayerName() + "'s initial hand is " ) );
       Logger.addToOutput( player.getPlayerName(), player.getHand() );
   }

   private static void isWinner( Player player ){
        boolean winner = true;
        int first = player.hand[0].getCardValue();

        for (Card element : player.hand) {
           if (element.getCardValue() != first) {
               winner = false;
            }
        }

        if ( winner == true ){
            Logger.addToOutput( player.getPlayerName(), ( player.getPlayerName() + " has won the game with a hand of " ) );
            Logger.addToOutput( player.getPlayerName(), player.getHand() );
            System.out.println( player.getPlayerName() + " has won the game with a hand of " );
            player.seeHand();
            System.exit(0);
        }
   }
}
```

The Player class
public class Player implements Runnable
    {
        Card[] hand;
        String playerName;
        int strategyChosen;
        int playerNumber;

```
    private boolean running = true;
    private boolean paused = false;

    public void setPaused( boolean paused ){
        this.paused = paused;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(running){
            if(!paused){
              synchronized(this){  
                  playGame();
                }
         }
       }
    }

    private void playGame(){
        synchronized(this){
        switch(strategyChosen){
             case 1 : playStratOne();
             break;
             case 2 : playStratTwo();
             break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void startPauseThread(){
     Thread add = new Thread( pauseInputThread );
     add.start();
   }


   static Thread pauseInputThread = new Thread(){
     private boolean running = true;
     private boolean paused = false;

      public void run(){ 
            while(running){
              if(!paused){
                  for(;;){
                    System.out.println("FEED ME");
                    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String result = Checks.userInputCheck( "[pPrR]$" );
                       if( result == "p" ){
                           for ( int i = 0; i < CardGame.players.length; i++ ){
                            CardGame.players[i].setPaused( true );
                        }
                    }
                }
              }
            }
       }
      };

    private Player(){
    }

    private int getPlayerNumber(){
        return playerNumber;
    }

    public Player( int strategy, int cardsInHand, int playerNumber ){
        hand = new Card[cardsInHand];
        strategyChosen = strategy;
        this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
        playerName = "Player " + playerNumber;
    }

    public String getPlayerName(){
        return playerName;
    }

    public void fillHand(){
       for ( int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++){
            hand[i] = new Card(0);
       }
    }

    public void setHand( int value, int index ){
        hand[index].setCardValue( value );
    }

    public void seeHand(){
        for ( int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++){
            System.out.println( hand[i].getCardValue() );
        }
    }

    public String getHand(){
        String result = "";
        for ( int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++ ){
            result = result +  hand[i].getCardValue() + " \n" ;
        } 
        return result;
    }

    public int getHandValue( Card card ){
        return card.getCardValue();
    }

    private void playStratOne(){
        System.out.println("fuck");
    }

    private void playStratTwo(){
        synchronized(this){
            int index = 0;
            System.out.println( getPlayerName() + " discards a " + hand[index].getCardValue() + " to deck " + playerNumber );
            CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber-1].add( new Card( getHandValue(hand[index])));

            for( int i = 1; i < hand.length+1; i++){
                if ( index == hand.length-1 ){
                    hand[index] = null;
                }else{
                    hand[index] = hand[index+i];
                    index = index + i; 
                }
            }
            if ( playerNumber == 1){
                System.out.println( getPlayerName() + " draws a " + ((CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber + CardGame.playersNum - 2].poll()).getCardValue()) + " from deck " + ( CardGame.playersNum ) );
                hand[index] = CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber + CardGame.playersNum - 2].poll();
            }else{
                System.out.println( getPlayerName() + " draws a " + (( CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber - 2].poll()).getCardValue())  + " from deck " + ( playerNumber - 1 ) );
                hand[index] = CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber - 2].poll();
            }

            System.out.println(getPlayerName()+ "'s hand is ");
            seeHand();
            for( int i = 0; i < CardGame.playingDeckArray.length; i++ ){
            }

            checkWinner();
        }
    }

    private void checkWinner(){
        boolean winner = true;
        int first = hand[0].getCardValue();

        for (Card element : hand) {
            if (element.getCardValue() != first) {
                winner = false;
            }
        }

        if ( winner == true ){
            Logger.addToOutput( getPlayerName(), ( getPlayerName() + " has won the game with a hand of " ) );
            Logger.addToOutput( getPlayerName(), getHand() );
            System.out.println( getPlayerName() + " has won the game with a hand of " );
            seeHand();
            System.exit(0);
        }
   }
}
```

The Card class

```
 public class Card
 { 
    int cardValue;

    private Card(){
    }

    public Card( int value ){
        cardValue = value;
    }

    public void setCardValue( int value ){
        cardValue = value;
    }

    public int getCardValue(){
        return cardValue;
    }

    public  int getCardValue( Card card ){
        return cardValue;
    }
}
```

The aim of the game is to have a hand of all the same value card.

I was wondering if there was a way to make the threads print in order, and also I dont understand why the nullPointers and IndexOutOfBounds errors occur

This is the result from a 2 player game with hand size of 2

```
Hello, how many players would you like
2
Thank You


How many cards should each player begin with
2
Thank You


Which strategy would you like to use 1 or 2
2
Thank You

The deck has been created 
It is called deckfile.txt 

Please enter the name of the deck file
deckfile.txt
Thank You

Player 1's hand is currently
1
3
Player 2's hand is currently
2
3
Player 1 discards a 1 to deck 1
Player 1 draws a 4 from deck 2
Player 2 discards a 2 to deck 2
Player 1's hand is 
Player 2 draws a 4 from deck 1
3
2
Player 2's hand is 
3
1
Player 1 discards a 3 to deck 1
Player 2 discards a 3 to deck 2
Player 1 draws a 2 from deck 2
Player 2 draws a 1 from deck 1
Player 1's hand is 
2
3
Player 1 discards a 2 to deck 1
Player 2's hand is 
1
3
Player 2 discards a 1 to deck 2
Player 2 draws a 2 from deck 1
Player 2's hand is 
3
```

This gives a nullPointer exception, and when i play a 5 player game with handsize of 5

```
Player 1's hand is currently
1
4
1
4
8
Player 2's hand is currently
2
1
1
3
1
Player 3's hand is currently
3
2
10
6
2
Player 4's hand is currently
3
7
5
8
6
Player 5's hand is currently
4
4
2
1
4
Player 1 discards a 1 to deck 1
Player 2 discards a 2 to deck 2
Player 5 discards a 4 to deck 5
Player 3 discards a 3 to deck 3
Player 4 discards a 3 to deck 4
```

I get the indexOutOfBounds exception

```
Exception in thread "Thread-8" Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at Player.playStratTwo(Player.java:132)
at Player.playGame(Player.java:38)
at Player.run(Player.java:27)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

apologies if i am asking too much, but help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the following code:

```
int index = 0;
System.out.println( getPlayerName() + " discards a " + hand[index].getCardValue() + " to deck " + playerNumber );
CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber-1].add( new Card( getHandValue(hand[index])));

for( int i = 1; i < hand.length+1; i++){
    if ( index == hand.length-1 ){
        hand[index] = null;
    }else{
        hand[index] = hand[index+i];
        index = index + i; 
    }
}
```

So, at the start of the for loop, index cannot have a different  value than 0.

If the hand.length is 5, say, then the loop is going to go from 1 to 5 - it is confusing to run while "i less than one more than the length of the array", but that's what you've got.  One potential problem with this is that java arrays start at 0, so if your array is length 5, then it has cards 0-4, not 1-5.  If you have the array declared as length of 6, this might be ok.  I haven't dug through all of your code to determine how you've declared it.

So the loop runs from 1 to 5; if the index is 4, then set that element to null.  So values at indices 1, 2, 3, and 5, will attempt to execute the other part of the if statement.  If it's 5, then you had better have an array that will accomodate an index of 6 (length of 7), since you have an index + i into the array.  Evidently you don't, because your error message says the 6 is an array index out of bounds.

Java error messages and stack traces are two of its most useful features.  They most often tell you what the problem is and where in the code it was discovered -- this is NOT universal in the programming world.  If you're going to program in Java, learn to trust your error messages, and learn to read them and get information from them as starting points to troubleshooting the problem.

In addition, let me say that the use of 'index' is confusing -- it appears to remain one count behind 'i' through the loop, except for what I assume is a typo with length + 1 and length - 1.  If you use i to iterate through the array elements, then can't i be used to compare to something to see where you are, what to do next, etc., instead of using another int?

Lastly, let me caution you that setting the last element of the array to null does not shorten the array.  If you had an array of 5 objects and you set the last to null, then you have an array with null in the 5th element, not an array of 4.  I don't know if you expected the length of the array to change, but it seemed possible you did given the code here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I feel i have over complicated teh index but what should happen is the should discard the first card in their hand to the appropriate Card queue, which will be the the 0th element in the array for player 1, the 1st element for player 2 etc. This represents the players discarding to the deck in 'front' of them. The players then draw from the deck 'behind' them so player 2 will draw from the deck in the 0th index, player 3 from the 1st index, but player 1 will draw from the last element in the array, the final deck between player 5 and 1. I just dont

Comment: understand why i get index error for diffrent amounts of players, surely, if the iteration is the issue i should get a consistent error. I also undestand that setting to null doesnt decrease the size of the array, i just wanted the player to discard the first card in thier hand then move the rest of the cards along to fill up the gap, and then set the final to null, then the player will draw from the deck and put it in the null index, the last card in their hand. p.s Thank you for the response

Comment: I have suggestions: eliminate the arrays and use ListArray instead.  You can remove an element from a ListArray, and the length of the ListArray will decrease by 1.  Then debug it instead of staring at it.  With eclipse or any reasonable development environment, set breakpoints and step through code to understand why values get to where they are.